# Accessing module level variables, from within a function in the module

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
#mymodule
var = None

def load():
    var = something()
```

Other module(s):

```
#secondmodule
import mymodule
mymodule.load()

#thirdmodule
from mymodule import var
print var #Shouldn't be None
```

But I don't know how to reference a modules variable from a function defined in the module.

Is this possible? Or am I going to need to put a global declaration in every place I wan't to use this.
Or am I going at this completely wrong?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just change the function definition to:

```
def load():
    global var # this line has been added to the original code
    var = something()
```

Global variables are read-only from sibling methods. More accurately unless a variable is specified as global, Python consider it as local, but a read access to a local variable name will reach module-level scope if the name is not present in local scope.

See also [use of “global” keyword in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693392/760767) and the [doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) for more details about the `global` statement

Comment: @dennmat Don't use global variables. If you think you need them it is usually a sign that your design is flawed.

Comment: @schlamar Thanks for the dogma. But no, there are perfectly legitimate use cases for global variables. And it was not the question anyway.

Comment: @Evpok Depends ;-) There is the one use case that you want to rewrite members of the current module. But in this case I prefer `sys.modules[__name__].var = something()`. ("Explicit is better than implicit.")

Comment: @schlamar in this particular case I was writing a small tool for myself at home and ran across this problem. In the interest of time and this not being a critical piece of software globals are fine. I agree with Evpok that even in bigger projects there is a time and place for globals just extremely rarely. Even more though because of how python works, these aren't truly "globals".

Comment: @schlamar Is it a joke? This is ugly, a newcomer wouldn't understand it any better than `global`, it unnecessarily expose complex module mechanics, and it requires the import of `sys`, all this just to comply to a questionable dogma, and word of God says “A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds.”. I prefer `global`.

Answer (score 24):

You seem to mostly have it. You are missing only the fact that "module-level" variables are called global in Python. (They are not truly global, but only global to the module they are declared in, in other words.)

In any function where you *modify* a global variable (you want to make the name refer to a different object), it must be declared global. So your `load()` function needs a `global var` at the beginning. If you are only using the value of a global variable, or if it is a mutable type such as a list and you are modifying it, but not changing the object that the name points to, you needn't declare it global.

The `import` statement is, as you have discovered, how you can import a module-level variable from one module into another.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, that was in-fact the solution, helps me understand globals and pythons stacks a little bit more now.

Comment: This answer my doubt, `. If you are only using the value of a global variable, or if it is a mutable type such as a list and you are modifying it, but not changing the object that the name points to, you needn't declare it global.` Thanks @kindall!

Comment: In my case, I was using global variable in my method, I was not changing it anywhere. On next call, it was empty. not sure why. :(